# Hash Table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, hashtable

Can anybody please explain hash table in SQL Server?

Is it same as a temp table? I searched for some examples in google for hash table, but can't find any

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you talking about tables prefixed with a `#` symbol? Or a hash table build step in an execution plan? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 5):

> Hashtable is used to store temporary data.
>
> 1.The Hashtable object contains items in key/value pairs. The keys are used as indexes, and very quick searches can be made for values by
> searching through their keys.
>
> 2.Temporary tables are a useful tool in SQL Server provided to allow for short term use of data. There are two types of temporary table in
> SQL Server, local and global.

When you use single # is define for Local Temporary Table, when use double # is define Global temporary tables

Please check this link.

http://www.nullskull.com/q/10298657/what-is-difference-between-temp-table-and-hash-table-in-sql--server.aspx (check more other links in this link to understand more)

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/